# how to insert local image into salesforce for custom tab?

Tags: admin

I'm trying to insert custom image from local storage like 'my document 'I"m not able to insert image from local storage to salesforce .Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To add a system local image for custom tab, you need to add your local image to salesforce Documents.
If you can't find the Documents tab in salesforce, the url is `<your_domain>.com/015`, like for accounts it is `<your_domain>.com/001`

Then you need to go to Setup > Tabs > "New" button > Tab Style field > Create your own style (in lookup popup) > "Insert image" button > choose any image from Documents.

Comment: Thanks Aditya for answer

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, you can mark it as answer, so it can help others also.